# How to select from a table where in a list and then diff that against the same list?

Tags: oracle

Here is what I need:

I have a `LIST` of *keys*:

```
A
B
C
D
```

A TABLE `keys` that contains:

```
A
B
**... and millions of other entries** ( but `NOT` `C` or `D` )
```

I want to see what is in the *list* `AND` NOT IN the *table* AND *list*.

the expected output would be:

```
C
D
```

Since `C` and `D` are in the `LIST` AND IN the `TABLE`.

I have found examples of how to create a table of a type and wrap the list I just could not get the syntax correct by putting together disparate examples to get what I want and they all failed.

Here is what I am stuck on:

> [42000][904] ORA-00904: "MISSING_KEY": invalid identifier

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MISSING_KEYS AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(256);

SELECT missing_key
FROM TABLE (MISSING_KEYS('A','B','C','D'))
WHERE missing_key NOT IN (
    SELECT key
    FROM schema.keys
    WHERE key IN ('A','B','C','D')
);
```

## How do I give the column from the `MISSING_KEYS` TYPE a name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I finally got to work:

```
CREATE
    OR
    REPLACE TYPE MISSING_KEYS AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(256);

SELECT column_value AS missing_key
FROM TABLE (MISSING_KEYS('A','B','C','D'))
WHERE column_value NOT IN (
    SELECT key
    FROM schema.keys
    WHERE key IN ('A','B','C','D')
) ORBER BY column_value;
```

The part that I was missing, the default name `column_value` is explained [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249201/what-is-the-default-column-name-given-to-a-table-type-with-a-single-column).

Answer (score 1):

If you only need your list to have the keys (I'm using `minus` to find the difference between the two lists, you could modify it to use `NOT IN` instead if you'd rather)

```
create type tbl_keys2 is table of varchar2(10);
/

create table tbl (
  key varchar2(10)
);

insert into tbl values( 'list' );
insert into tbl values( 'of' );

with keys as (
  select *
    from table( tbl_keys2( 'list', 'of', 'some', 'keys' ))
)
select k.column_value key
  from keys k
minus
select t.key
  from tbl t;
```

If your list potentially needs to have multiple columns (i.e. a `key` and a `value` where you're looking for everything that doesn't match), you can create an object type that can have those additional columns and do

```
create type obj_keys is object( key varchar2(10) );
/

create type tbl_keys is table of obj_keys;
/

with keys as (
  select *
    from table( tbl_keys( obj_keys('list'), 
                          obj_keys('of'), 
                          obj_keys('some'), 
                          obj_keys('keys') ))
)
select k.key
  from keys k
minus
select t.key
  from tbl t;
```

Comment: it is not the difference between two lists, it is the difference between a list and table and the list again.

Answer (score 0):

The `TABLE()` function needs to take in an SQL Nested Table or Pipeline Function.

Newer versions of Oracle allow for PL/SQL Tables and the Polymorphic Table Function (a different type of Pipeline Function).

To create an SQL Nested Table User Defined Type:

```
create or replace type vc2_arr as table of varchar2(4000)
```

Putting it to use:

```sql
with keys as (
    select 'some' key from dual union all
    select 'keys' key from dual
)
select column_value as key
from table( vc2_arr('list','of','some','keys') )
where column_value not in ( select key from keys where key in ( 'list', 'of', 'some', 'keys' ) );
```

Although, you may want to review your Business Requirement.  You can find "rows in A that don't exist in B" by using the `minus` keyword.

Alternative solution:

```sql
with keys as (
    select 'some' key from dual union all
    select 'keys' key from dual
)
select column_value as key
from table( vc2_arr('list','of','some','keys') )
minus
select key from keys
```