# What is the default column name given to a TABLE() type with a single column

Tags: oracle, syntax, default-value

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MISSING_KEYS AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(256);

SELECT [¿what goes here?] as missing_key
FROM TABLE (MISSING_KEYS('A','B','C','D'))
```

#### What is the default column name that should be in `[¿what goes here?]` in the above example[?](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Answer (score 0):

#### [column_value](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns004.htm#SQLRF50950) Pseudocolumn

> When you refer to an `XMLTable` construct without the `COLUMNS` clause, **or
>   when you use the `TABLE` function to refer to a scalar nested table
>   type**, the database returns a virtual table with a single column. This
>   name of this pseudocolumn is `COLUMN_VALUE`.

#### Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MISSING_KEYS AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(256);

SELECT column_value AS missing_key
FROM TABLE (MISSING_KEYS('A','B','C','D'))
```